# Convergence of Isoclines

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a differential equation $y' = f(x,y)$, then I know isoclines are defined as :

$S_c = \{(x,y)|f(x,y) = c\}$ where $c$ is any real number.

Now, consider $y'= x-y$, for this equation isoclines are given by :

$x-y =c$, Now , graphically I can see that all the isoclines asymptotically converge to $x = y+1$

But, how do I show this fact analytically ?

Any hints will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us solve the linear differential equation
$$y'+y=x$$

Without RHS
$$y_h'=-y_h \implies y_h=\lambda e^{-x}$$

A particular solution $y_p=\lambda(x) e^{-x} $ satisfies

$$\lambda'(x)=xe^x$$
or
$$\lambda(x)=e^x(x-1)$$

So, the general solution will be
$$y=y_h+y_p=\lambda e^{-x}+x-1$$

When $ x\to +\infty\;  $, $ \;\lambda e^{-x} \to 0 $ and

$ \; f(x,y)= x-y\to 1$.